# There's a new Ask a Question page!

Tags: discussion, questions, user-interface

[The new ask page is now live on the network!](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/344513/311001) is the post on main meta (meta.stackexchange.com) describing the thought process behind and the new features of the Ask A Question redesign.

Check it out and leave any feedback on the MSE post linked above.

For convenience, [here's a link to the new Ask a Question page on mainsite](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) and [on this Meta](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/ask).

Comment: I feel like the obvious question is: does this give us a way to prompt askers to specify what system they are asking about?

Comment: @Someone_Evil I think it might. We're investigating.

Comment: @Someone_Evil: Sort of! It's been confirmed to us that it's possible to customize tag guidance that can appear in a box when clicking the tag bar, and the general guidance that appears on the right side (though such changes need to be made by a CM, at least at the moment). You can see examples in the screenshots in the MSE post. I'm still waiting for guidance on how customizable those two things will be, and on what can/should be included in them (e.g. markdown/character limits); they did reply to my question(s) saying they plan to include such guidance.

Comment: ...I see some of that info's in the MSE post itself: "As you can see, any existing custom guidance on "How to ask," "How to tag," or any custom error or warning messages your site may already have in place will still be there, and will still be customizable with the same restraints (basic HTML, using paragraphs, lists, links) as before: [...] - The text in the tag popover, between "Tags help the right people..." and the bullet points (seen with custom text in screenshot 2, and with the default text on screenshot 3)."

Comment: and continued: "[...] - Tag-related error messages, regex-based (seen with custom text in screenshot 4, and with the default text on screenshot 5)."

Answer (score 2):

I have made a suggestion on how they ought to improve the first screen that a new user sees.

[Here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/344541/380710), if any of you want to add anything.

I'd like us to do that here as well.

Comment: Left a comment on your answer. That said, the "Before you post paragraph is the start of the section of the the "Asking a good question" popover that isn't customizable (everything above that is customizable).

Comment: @V2Blast That needs to change, IMO, hence my suggestion.